# Verify: If $A$ is a bounded set and $f: A \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, then $f(A)$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Prove if $A$ is a bounded set and $f: A \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, then $f(A)$ is bounded.

*Note: Proofs are readily available; this question is to verify and critique this proof.*

**Proof:** Let $\bar A$ be the closure of $A$.  By the Continuous Extension Theorem, we can extend $f$ to continuous $\hat f: \bar A \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $\hat f(\bar A) \supseteq f(A)$.  $\bar A$ is compact since it is the closure of a bounded set, and therefore $\hat f(\bar A)$ has a max and min, and is bounded as well.  Thus, $f(A)$, as a subset of $\hat f(\bar A)$, is bounded.

**Questions:**

1. Is this proof correct?
2. Can the exposition be improved?
3. This seems simpler than the standard proof I've seen (e.g. [https://math.byu.edu/~tfisher/documents/classes/2017/fall/341/solutions/solutions21.pdf](https://math.byu.edu/%7Etfisher/documents/classes/2017/fall/341/solutions/solutions21.pdf) 4.4.4(b)), which is (condensed):

> Assume $f(A)$ is unbounded.  Construct $(y_n) \in f(A)$ such that $y_{n+1} > y_n + 1$ (WLOG).  Construct $(x_n) \in A$ such that $y_n = f(x_n)$.  There exists subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converging to $x$ [*].  Consequently, $|x_{n_{k}} - x_{n_{k+1}}| \to |x - x| = 0$, but $|f(x_{n_{k}}) - f(x_{n_{k+1}})| > 1$, and $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

> [*] If $A$ is closed, $x \in A$.  If $A$ is not closed, $x$ may be outside the domain of $f$, but this presents no problem, as we never take $f(x)$, only $f(x_n)$.  *(This note isn't spelled out in the source, but I believe it correct).*

Am I missing something?

Comment: The proof is good. It's not really a definite positive or negative, but it uses more heavy (or relatively heavy) machinery than the other proof you quoted. The advantage of yours is that it comes out more elegantly, with the complexities better tidied away behind other results. On the other hand, it is somehow less direct and more opaque, which may render it less suitable for teaching introductory analysis.

Comment: Perhaps one would prefer a proof that also proves: If $A$ is a bounded metric space and $f : A to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous, then $f(A)$ is bounded.  The proof needs no extension theorem.

Comment: @GEdgar If $A$ is an arbitrary bounded metric space, how do we know that it has the Bolzano-Weierstrass property and $(x_{n_k})$ converges to an $x \in A$?

Comment: @SRobertJames ... and the proof needs no Bolzano-Weierstrass property.  You would need that if you want to go from "continuous" to "uniformly continuous", but assuming "uniformly continuous" we do not need to do that.

Comment: @GEdgar Without Bolzano-Weierstrass, how do you know that for $(x_n) \in A$ there exists a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct and well written, but not really "simpler" than the (not really "standard") one you quote, because yours relies as well on sophisticated arguments (and the other one does not need your additional note). Here is a truly simpler proof:

Let $\delta>0$ be such that
$$\forall x,y\in A\quad(|x-y|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<1).$$
Since $A$ is bounded, it is contained in a finite union of open intervals $I_1,\dots,I_N$ of length $<\delta,$ so that
$f(A)$ is contained in $\bigcup_{k=1}^Nf(I_k),$ which is a finite union of bounded subsets, hence bounded. Thus, $f(A)$ is bounded.

Comment: $f(I_k)$ is bounded because we can choose $z \in I_k$ and for all $x \in I_k$ we have $|f(x)| < |f(z)| + 1$?

Comment: @Jordi yes or equivalently, because [a metric space is bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set#Definition_in_a_metric_space) iff [its diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Bounded_and_totally_bounded_spaces) is finite.

Answer (score 1):

This looks good. Also notice how the hypothesis that $f$ is *uniformly* continuous is essential.

To see this, consider $A = (0, 1)$ with $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Clearly, $A$ is bounded and $f$ is continuous, but $f(A) = (1, \infty)$ is unbounded. Of course, $f$ is *not* uniformly continuous on this open interval that runs up against the asymptote!